# FluentValidator isInEnum Not validate for first item

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a fluent validator:

```
 public MyValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(t => t.Gender)
                .IsInEnum()
                .NotEmpty();
            //...
        }
```

Gender is enum type

```
public enum Gender
  {
    NotSpecified,
    Male,
    Female,
  }
```

test method for all enum values

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(Gender.NotSpecified)]
[InlineData(Gender.Female)]
[InlineData(Gender.Male)]
public void WhenGenderIsInEnum_ShouldValidate(Gender gender)
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new MyObject {Gender = gender};

    // Act
    var result = _validator.TestValidate(model);

    // Assert
    result
        .ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(s => s.Gender);
}
```

test for male and female are ok, but for fist item 'NotSpecified' it return an error

```
Validation Errors:
[0]: 'Gender' must not be empty.
```

any ideas?

Comment: Element `NotSpecified` has propbably the numeric value "0", which is validated as "being empty". Just get rid of `.NotEmpty`. It cannot possibly be.

Comment: @Fildor by removing `NotEmpty`, request doesn't validate correct, because gender should be required field, I tried to add `NotNull` instead of `NotEmpty`, but is not correct validation, is allow request without gender field

Comment: But in that case, it was correct in the first place. "NotSpecified" _is_ an invalid value. You may consider simply overriding the error message with for example "Gender must be specified".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe its because the NotSpecified enum is automatically assigned value 0 and the fluent validator checks if the `value == default`

Try changing the value type to nullable.